# How to Update Description Field?

Tags: trigger, workflow

I am trying to update description field in opportunity based on Amount field if we give Amount 100 in Description filed need to Update Hundred in text form how can i achieve this requirement Any one Help me to do the update description field in opportunity.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Description will only contain amount in text like "one hundred twenty"?

Comment: You can try process Builder feature. You can invoke a Apex Class from a Process Builder to update Description field of an Opportunity based on Amount field changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/business_process_automation/process_builder)** feature.

You can invoke a Apex Class from a Process Builder to update Description field of an Opportunity based on Amount field changes.

Check below links for a reference.

[Getting started with process builder](https://automationchampion.com/2015/07/09/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-33-call-an-apex-method-from-a-process/) from Automation Champion

[Number to Word conversion using Salesforce Apex](http://salesforcewithkiran.blogspot.ch/2013/05/number-to-words-in-apex.html) from Kiran

Comment: Hi Thank you for responding if we are going to use apex class in process builder need to use  @InvocableMethod but when i am tring add this annotation trowing error **Error: Compile Error: Unsupported parameter type Integer. Valid InvocableMethod parameters must be List types like List<T> where T is a supported parameter type. at line 14 column 25**